# Loading images into a lightbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

So i know I'm screwing this up somewhere but I can't figure it out.

I am running a lightbox called light gallery.
I have lightgallery.min.js and lightgallery.min.css referenced, and the files in the correct folders. /css and /js

To dynamically call images i'm trying to run the following script. (taken from here [LightGallery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/dynamic.html) I have simply referenced an image on my system.

```
 $('.#dynamic').on('click', function() {

        $(this).lightGallery({
            dynamic: true,
            dynamicEl: [{
                "src": '/img/splash/header.jpg',
                'thumb': '/img/splash/header.jpg',
                'subHtml': '<h4>Cover</h4><p>Test image</p>'
            }, {
                "src": '/img/splash/header.jpg',
                'thumb': '/img/splash/header.jpg',
                'subHtml': "<h4>Bowness Bay</h4><p>A beautiful Sunrise this morning taken En-route to Keswick not one as planned but I'm extremely happy I was passing the right place at the right time....</p>"
            }, {
                "src": '/img/splash/header.jpg',
                'thumb': '/img/splash/header.jpg',
                'subHtml': "<h4>Coniston Calmness</h4><p>Beautiful morning</p>"
            }]
        })

    });
```

I have  button on my page with the id of dynamic, however I cannot get the lightbox to load.

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg mrb50" id="dynamic">Launch Gallery
                             </button>
```

I have tried placing the script in the  head and also the body of my page but I'm just not able to get it to run. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: change `('.#dynamic')` to `('#dynamic')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('#dynamic').click(function() {
```

Instead of

```
 $('.#dynamic').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: Yes that was it... god what an idiot i am.... That was driving me crazy haha... Thanks so much...

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].